# Getting an error when trying to push my files to heroku "git push heroku master ERROR"

Tags: python, django, heroku, decoupling

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement decouple==0.0.7

I am following this tutorial :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5WXNI3Dq8U&t=1208s

I need help narrowing down what is causing this kind of error. Would having the latest python package be the issue ?.

Comment: Please show the full traceback - we can't tell why the error occurred from that line alone. I see [decouple 0.07](https://pypi.org/project/decouple/0.0.7/) requires Python 3.7. Perhaps the problem is your Python version. See [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) for instructions to specify a Python runtime.

Comment: I am using python 3.7.7 and here is my log file 

Python app detected

Installing python-3.6.10

Installing pip

Installing SQLite3

Installing requirements with pip


       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement decouple==0.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_08164e4812c54867aab4849f3b4dbc33/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)

       ERROR: No matching distribution found for decouple==0.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_08164e4812c54867aab4849f3b4dbc33/requirements.txt (line 2))

Comment: Please don't post code or tracebacks in the comments, it's difficult to read. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: The error message says `Installing python-3.6.10`. As I suspected, it looks as if Heroku is using Python 3.6.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I saw that as we were talking and realized the same.

Comment: Any advice on how to get heroku to run python 3.7.7 ?. I read about creating a runtime.txt file and putting the exact version in it. However, nothing is changing when  I git push heroku master. I have that file located in my git directory.

Comment: Adding `runtime.txt` to the root of your repo should do the trick. You haven't shown the layout of your files in your project, so I can't be sure you've put it in the correct place, but *in my git directory* sounds correct to me. Did you remember to `git add` the file and commit before pushing?